# Is there a way to add a get variable to the php include

Tags: php

I am trying to do this ...is it possible

```
<?php include("includes/sidebar.php?show_hide_tab=true"); ?>
```

because some pages dont need some logic in the sidebar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do this

```
<?php
    $show_hide_tab = true;

    include('includes/sidebar.php');
?>
```

The scope of the `$show_hide_tab` variable will fall through to the include script.

Comment: For clarity, here's what the [php manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) has to say: "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. **Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file**, from that point forward."

Comment: Alternately (and lame) `$_GET['show_hide_tab'] = true; include("includes/sidebar.php");` (comment rather than post as you should get the credit, and it's lame.